# How does Vertx java handle Oracle's RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO clause

Tags: java, oracle, reactive-programming, vert.x

I was trying to implement RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO clause feature in vertx java. I saw many example but was not able to figure out. Didn't find PreparedStatement or registerReturnParameter kind of thing. Can you please help. My Query looks like

```
DECLARE 
    TYPE updatedId IS TABLE OF Table1.col2%TYPE; 
    XupdatedId updatedId;
BEGIN 
    UPDATE TABLE1 
         SET col1 = 'OK' WHERE col2 IN ('abc','def')
   RETURNING col2 
        BULK COLLECT INTO XupdatedId; 
   FOR i IN 1..XupdatedId.LAST
   LOOP
        IF i > 1 THEN
            dbms_output.put_line (XupdatedId(i));
        END IF;   
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I am using below vertx imports

```
import io.vertx.ext.sql.ResultSet;
import io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLClient;
import io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLConnection;
import io.vertx.ext.sql.UpdateResult;
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the `ResultSet` like: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/#_callable_statements

Comment: yes but it is for stored procedure or function. I want to use normal query.